# How to print a long in jasmin?

Tags: java, jvm, jasmin

I can print an integer in jasmin like so:

```
getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
bipush 7
invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(I)V
```

What would the argument to `println` be to print a long (64-bit integer)?

I have tried 
`invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(L)V` but the assembler tells me that `(L)V` is an illegal signature. (Note: `System.out` and a long are both on the stack when I try to call this method.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was previously having trouble with this as well. `L` is reserved for literal object names and can not be used to print longs. However, `J` can be used to print long (64 bit) values.

So, your code would just be:

`getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
ldc2_w 7
invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(J)V`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `l2i` to print small long (64 bit) values, but this could cause you to lose the sign bit and additional information. You should use

`invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(J)V`